# Using DDL, how can the default value for a Numeric(8,0) field be set to today's date as YYYYMMDD?

Tags: date, timestamp, db2, ddl

I'm trying to convert this, which works:

```
create_timestamp for column
   CREATETS TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

to something that works like this, but this code is ***not*** working:

```
date_created for column
   DTCREATE NUMERIC(8,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMMDD'),
```

Can anyone advise DDL to accomplish what I'm going for? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When asking for help with Db2, always specify your Db2-server platform (Z/OS , i-series,  linux/unix/windows)  and Db2-server version, because the answer can depend on these facts.

The default-clause for a column does not have syntax that you expect, and that is the reason you get a syntax error.

It's can be a mistake to store a date as a numeric, because it causes no end of hassle to programmers and reporting tools, and data exchange.  It's usually a mistake based on false assumptions.

If you want to store a date (not a timestamp) then use the column datatype DATE which lets you use:

`DTCREATE DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT DATE`

How you choose, or future programmers choose , to render the value of a date on the SQL output is a different matter.

Comment: Using a date field won't help, I'm all but forced to use YYYYMMDD in this case to expedite the rewrite of some green screens currently looking at this schema. If I can't get this DDL to work I can manually work around.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to emulate a `DEFAULT` clause with such an unsupported function instead.

```
CREATE TRIGGER MYTAB_BIR
BEFORE INSERT ON MYTAB
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (N.DATE_CREATED IS NULL)
SET DATE_CREATED = VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMMDD');
```

Comment: I tried including this in the same DDL file after my "CREATE TABLE.... ;" syntax, and am receiving an error.

library: MYLIB
table: HEADER
column: DTCREATE

CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_MYLIB_HEADER
BEFORE INSERT ON MYLIB.HEADER
REFERENCING NEW AS N
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (N.DTCREATE IS NULL)
SET DTCREATE = VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMMDD');

Can anyone confirm if the trigger needs to be created/run in its own file? Or, can this work and perhaps my syntax is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: It's a different problem not related to the original one. Are you able to use some different tool like IBM i Access or whatever other one (some JDBC-based, for example) to create the trigger?